# Rendering v-for items in columns with Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-for

I am trying to render v-switch elements with a v-for loop but cannot manage to render them in two columns. Anybody got any ideas?

My code looks like this:

```
            <v-row>
                <v-col>
                    <v-switch
                    v-for="item in dominantBottomSubstrate"
                    :key="item.id"
                    v-model="selectedDominantBottomSubstrate"
                    multiple
                    :value="item.name"
                    :label="item.value"
                    >
                    </v-switch>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should chunk `dominantBottomSubstrate` array in 2 size. From [ 1,2,3,4 ] to [ [1,2], [3,4] ] and then iterate it in `v-row` and `v-col` element. **lodash** has already implemented this function, see https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
        <v-row>
            <v-col col="6"
             v-for="item in dominantBottomSubstrate"
             :key="item.id">
                <v-switch
                v-model="selectedDominantBottomSubstrate"
                multiple
                :value="item.name"
                :label="item.value"
                />
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
```